# I am trying to increase the size of my outputed .doc file

Tags: vb.net

I've created a fake file generator what it does is generate an
empty .doc file.  The only way I've managed to increase  the size of .doc
is by adding useless text in the document.  However I would to know
if there is an alternative way of increasing the size of the .doc file
probably by adding random garbage bytes?   I would like the output of the .doc file at a fixed size 250kb.

However if this is incapable of being done can you make the text
invisible by default?  I want the text invisible when the user opens 
the document.  This is another alternative of increasing the file size
if the first option I recommended failed

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub InfluenceButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Build.Click
        Dim i As Integer

        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 200

        For i = 0 To 200
            ProgressBar1.Value = i
        Next

    End Sub
    Private Property namefile As String

    Private Sub Build_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Build.Click

        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Doc|*.doc"
        sfd.Title = "Save a Doc File"

        sfd.ShowDialog()

        ' If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
        If sfd.FileName <> "" Then

        End If

        Using W As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sfd.FileName)
            W.Write("\x41\xe2\xf5\x51\x68//sh\x68/bin\x89\xe3\x51\x54\x53\x53\xb0\x3b\xcd\x80 \x41\xe2\xf5\x51\x68//sh\x68/bin\x89\xe3\x51\x54\x53\x53\xb0\x3b\xcd\x80")
        End Using
        Pump(sfd.FileName, 2093)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

use command prompt Processstartinfo by using this:-

```
fsutil file createnew test.txt 256000
```

this creates a file with no real information in it, to a specified size which 256000 bytes is 250KB :).